# Is it bubble sort or insertion sort?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures

I'm trying to implement the insertion sort algorithm without looking implementations. However, I'm confused that if my code is insertion sort or bubble sort.

Insertion sort:
[image]

Bubble sort: [image]

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int[] arr = {3,8,1,6,2};
        Sort(arr);
        foreach(var x in arr) Console.WriteLine(x+ ", ");
    }
    
    private static void Sort(int[] arr)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < arr.Length; ++i)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j)
            {
                if (arr[i] < arr[j])
                {
                    Swap(ref arr[j] , ref arr[i] );
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    static void Swap(ref int x, ref int y)
    {
        int temp = x;
        x = y;
        y = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: The key difference is that bubble sort only swaps *adjacent* elements, while insertion sort can move an item an *arbitrary* distance (though this can require shifting a number of elements by one spot to make room if you are sorting an array in place).

Comment: The gifs clearly show how insertion sort and bubble sort work. Your code is neither of those. Bubble sort compares, and optionally swaps, adjacent elements. Your code clearly does not do that. Instead it swaps widely separated elements. Insertion sort is characterized by lifting one element, moving zero or more elements, and then dropping the original element. Insertion sort does not perform two-element swaps. So the fact that your code contains a `Swap` function is a sure sign that it's not a selection sort.

Comment: @user3386109 selection sort uses swap as well. Why do you consider it as a sign?

Comment: @user3386109 sir, may you confuse insertion sort with selection sort? There is no animation belonging to selection sort. Can you share a link including your-version selection sort?

Comment: @snr Yes, the words "selection sort" at the end of my previous comment were supposed to be "insertion sort". Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand this question: the animations are quite clear, and you can clearly match the provided code with only one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Insertion sort doesn't swap the current value but the others then it finds a proper gap to put.
Bubble sort bubbles the large values up, that is, it may swap the current value.